# Can't change resolution to 1680x1050

Tags: linux, resolution, xorg, xrandr

I am installing Elementary OS (I had the same issue with plain Ubuntu and Fedora, Mint and some other distros) on a Sony VAIO VGC-JS1E/S and everything works perfectly OK except I cannot change the resolution to 1680x1050 (which is the default). The mode isn't listed in available resolutions.

I already tried to use `xrandr` to add the mode but it doesn't help

```
$ cvt 1680 1050 
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode  "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1680x1050_60.00
```

Results in:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

Also with reduced blanking (-r)

```
cvt -r 1680 1050 
# 1680x1050 59.88 Hz (CVT 1.76MA-R) hsync: 64.67 kHz; pclk: 119.00 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050R"  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050R"  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync
$ xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1680x1050R
```

Gives same result:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  30
  Current serial number in output stream:  31
```

I also tried this method http://www.x.org/wiki/FAQVideoModes/ (PowerStrip) and was able to create a working `xorg.conf` but it seems to ignore these settings and the right resolution still isn't working.

Can anybody tell me if there is any possibility to add this mode to the available resolutions?

The video card in this machine is a Intel GMA X4500HD

PS: I am trying to convince someone to stop using Windows and this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I spend 2 hour to solve similar problem and problem was in vga cable. Replace vga cable I can change resolution to 1920x1080 without using xrandr or xorg it's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that "" don't seem to work correctly on the syntax, and refresh rate should be included.

Would of been way easier with a radeon, but try this:

1. Spawn a mode by using cvt
   Example: `cvt 1680 1050 60`
   That'll get you something similar to:

   1680x1050 59.96 Hz (CVT 1.76MA-R) hsync: 65.28 kHz; pclk: 146.24 MHz
   Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.24  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
2. Parse it to xrandr:

   xrandr --newmode 1680x1050_60.00  146.24  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

Note that exact frequencies may differ, but resolutions numbers are the same.

3. Now you can add it to the possible res table:

   xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00

Then you should be able to correctly select it.

Comment: Hi @Overmind, thank you very much for your answer. I followed your steps but unfortunately I am getting exactly the same result when I am trying to add the new mode to "LVDS1" display :(

Comment: Can you write in here what responses you get when using each command ?

Comment: I am getting the same error message as above: "X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)".
Just to be clear: I am executing xrandr --addmode LVDS1 1680x1050_60.00. Is this correct?

Comment: Try xrandr --fb 1680x1050  .Then test scaling with xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1.0x1.0 (and then 1.5 1.5 just to test if the system actually works correctly).